# JPA (EBeans) Errors with Relations

Tags: html, jpa, playframework, entity, ebean

First of all I am programming a webapplication with Playframework 2.2.2 which is using Ebeans.
I will start with the code because then it is easier to explain what my problem is:

This is one of my models:

```
@Entity
public class Topic extends Model {

    @Id
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    private User createdBy;
    private Integer popular;
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date created;
    private boolean over18;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

The model has this method:

```
/**
 * Return the number of opinions that exist on a specific Topic
 */
public int countOpinions() {
    return Opinion.find.where().eq("topic", this).findRowCount();
}
```

This is my second relevant model:

```
@Entity
public class Opinion extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long opinionId;
    @Constraints.Pattern("pos|neg|neut")
    private String type;
    @ManyToOne
    private Topic topic;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    private int rating;
    private String text;
    private boolean reported;
        @ManyToOne
        private Opinion parent;
}
```

containing this static method

```
public static Model.Finder<Long, Opinion> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Opinion>(Long.class, Opinion.class);
```

Here we have the call in the HTML

```
        @topics.map { topic =>
            <th scope="col" id="name">@topic.getTitle()</th>
            <th scope="col" id="description">@topic.getDescription()</th>
            <th scope="col" id="opinions">@topic.countOpinions()</th>
        }
```

**Problem:**

Ok so the countOpinions() is not working correctly. I created some testvalues, which should show the value 2 for a specific test Topic, but it shows the value 0. Im not sure how Ebeans is saving those fields with a type that I have created for myself, but afaik it should work like this.

I have tried already to override the equals methods in the Models, cause I figured it may be used, but apparently it isnt.

Thx for every help.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it quickly, works fine

```
private FakeApplication fakeApplication;

@Before
public void setup() {
    fakeApplication = fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase());
    start(fakeApplication);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    stop(fakeApplication);
}

@Test
public void countOpinionsTest() {
    // given
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setTitle("test");
    topic.save();
    Opinion opinion1 = new Opinion();
    opinion1.setOpinionId((long) 1);
    opinion1.save();
    Opinion opinion2 = new Opinion();
    opinion2.setOpinionId((long) 2);
    opinion2.save();
    // when
    opinion1.setTopic(topic);
    opinion1.update();
    opinion2.setTopic(topic);
    opinion2.update();
    // then
    assertThat(topic.countOpinions()).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

Do you have your ebean config set and the entity in the according package (here models)?

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Comment: Just made a similar JUnit Test, and also works. Quite strange since I use the same test db data for my Junit Test, as for the rendered Web app. hm... I do use those settings btw.
EDIT: Found the error, I made something wrong in the test values for the database. Thx for the help